# Negative Margin in WPF

Tags: wpf, margin

When I set margin edges negative values, I want them still be inside the parent panel, but to cropped with parent border.
This is What i have:[image]

and this is what I want (made in paint):
[image]

My XAML:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="113,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Background="#FFF97C7C">
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F5F4" Height="56" Margin="-48,-22,-46,63" Stroke="Black"/>
    </Grid>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ClipToBounds`:

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="113,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Background="#FFF97C7C">
    <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F5F4" Height="56" Margin="-48,-22,-46,63" Stroke="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image: Result]