# Keeping correct XAML layout when browser is resized

Tags: wpf

I have a XAML window that the layout is done using a main grid. The problem is when the browser is resized the controls in the second and third columns move to the right and the window's layout is no longer correct. I have pasted the XAML below. I think the layout of a WPF window should be grid based with all controls residing in the window's master grid. Is this the proper layout design for WPF or is there a different recommended layout pattern?

```html
<Window x:Class="MasterPage.Intake1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MasterPage.View"
    Title="Intake 1" Height="900" Width="1000" Background="#FFD9DDE8" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="190*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="275*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="500*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
       <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">
            <Image Source="Images\header.jpg" Height="47" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Height="80"  Width="350" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,-23,0,0">
            <Image Source="Images\DSPASS_logo.png" Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="70" />
      </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock FontSize="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="25" Width="300" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
            <Label FontSize="10" Name="Namelabel" Width="250" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#1664A1" Content="Welcome to DS PASS:"/>               
        </TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Height="290" Width="975" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1">
            <Label Height="36" FontSize="16" Content="Post Identification" Background="#FF014E7E" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="-5,0,-18,0"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="_wordLength" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="235,0,200,0">
                <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="ApplicantType_TextBlock" Text="Applicant Type" Width="110" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                <ComboBox Height="25" x:Name="textBoxWordLength" Width="400" Margin="10,5"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="_integerWordLength" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="235,0,200,0">
                <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="textBlockIntegerWordLength" Text="Person Type" Width="110" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                <ComboBox Height="25" x:Name="textBoxIntegerWordLength" Width="400" Margin="10,5"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="_Post" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="235,0,200,20">
                <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="Post_TextBlock" Text="Post" Width="110" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                <ComboBox Height="25" x:Name="Post_TextBox" Width="400" Margin="10,5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="130" Margin="15,-120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
            <Label Height="36" FontSize="16" Content="Applicant Employment" Background="#FF004A78" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="-5,0,-18,0"/>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="_max1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="1,0,355,0">
                        <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="maxTextBlock1" Text="Employee ID" Width="100" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,15,459,5" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="maxTextBox1" Width="400" Margin="0,-5,90,25"/>
                    </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="965" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Label Height="36" FontSize="16" Content="English Version of Name" Background="#FF005183" Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Padding="4,5,5,5"/>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="_LastName" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="LastName_TextBlock" Text="Last Name/Surname" Margin="55,5,459,5" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="LastName_TextBox" Width="500" Margin="55,5,459,5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="_FirstName" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="FirstName_TextBlock" Text="First Name" Margin="55,0,459,0" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="FirstName_TextBox" Width="500" Margin="55,0,459,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="_MiddleName" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="MiddleName_TextBlock" Text="Middle Name" Margin="55,5,459,5" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="MiddleName_TextBox" Width="500" Margin="55,5,459,5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="_ExtendedName" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="ExtendedName_TextBlock" Text="Extended name (Tribal, Jr., III, etc.)" Margin="55,5,372,5" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="Extended_TextBox" Width="500" Margin="55,5,459,5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="230" Margin="-250,400,0,0" Width="480" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="_Aliases" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="-15,0,0,0" Height="144">
                        <TextBlock Height="20" x:Name="Aliases_TextBlock" Text="Aliases" Margin="40,-5,0,5" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="Aliases_TextBox" Width="500" Margin="43,5"/>
                        <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="Aliases_TextBox1" Width="500" Margin="43,5"/>
                        <TextBox Height="25" x:Name="Aliases_TextBox2" Width="500" Margin="43,5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--<Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,132,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF72C772" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="1242" Height="36"/>
        <Button Content="Continue" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,139,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Click="Page1_Continue_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Save Draft" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,139,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>-->
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,400,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF52BB52" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="983" Height="36">
        </Label>
        <Button Content="Save Draft" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,408,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" />
        <Button x:Name="ContinueButton_Page2" Content="Continue" Grid.Column="1"  Width="125" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="200,408,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="btnContinue_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want control of the alignment during resizing, think Grid. In more complex situations, think Grids inside a Grid. A picture says it better

[image]

You have your MainGrid with only rows, no columns. The blue headers get rows of their own and
the orange containers are Grids themselves (with possibly a margin left and right).

Now you shouldn't try to divide the available space with all "...*" width values.

In this example you could use it for dead space only, e.g. the yellow columns with Width="*".
The blue columns would be Width="Auto" (or pixels).

Topping it off with a MinWidth for the Window corresponding with the width you need for the bottom Grid. Also consider wrapping your MainGrid in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: Your post is great! Since you explained WPF layout graphically as well as a written explanation as well I can do proper design layout now. There is one thing I still am unsure of and don't want to add a new post I want to ask it in this post. My follow up question is should negative margin values be used?

Comment: @lelizabeth You're welcome. I haven't used negative margins myself. Seems like the main purpose would be for [clipping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761307/negative-margin-in-wpf). For straithforward GUI's like these Control/Container Margin or Padding should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

What I needed was to not allow resizing of the web browser. To do this I removed the minimize/maximize buttons To do that I used the following attribute:

```
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```